# Concise book about QFT suggestion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I have the following books about QFT:

- Peskin-Schroeder
- Lancaster-Blundell
- Iliopoulos-Tomaras

I would like to know if there is a QFT that is as concise as Dirac's book about general Relativity.

What I found useful about Dirac's book was that it developed most mathematical machinery "from scratch" with very little comments. I would like a "quick reference" QFT book that allows one to study the matter from a more mathematical perspective, rather than using a lot of physical analogies as in the books I have read.
As an example, I would like to see "This is the QED Lagrangian. Those are the consequences", but a more classical, experiment driven approach is appreciated if it is strictly functional to the development of the theory and if it is kept as concise as possible.

Ideally the book should be:

- More or less "self-contained", allowing a student with all prerequisites to learn introductory QFT from scratch (at least to renormalization)
- As concise as possible (ideally also in the number of pages)

I would also like lecture notes or papers, it does not have to be a book.

Comment: I would like to suggest Srednicki's lecture notes or Sidney Coleman's. Weinberg's book are also great, but a bit too heavy for first encounter

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that such a task might be impossible (giving a self-contained explanation of quantum field theory and using only a few pages)? Also, do you want to know _why_ certain equations are valid or do you just want to know what equations to apply? For example the first four chapters of Peskin and Schroeder are necessary for developing the logic underlying Feynman diagrams, but if you didn't care why Feynman diagrams worked you there might be another resource that skips that justification.

Comment: There's a few things to be aware of. (1) Unlike GR, which is a single concrete theory that you can write on an index card, QFT is a *framework* for constructing theories. (2) A lot of formalism is needed to write the equations for any specific, interesting QFT, and different theories may require different formalisms. (3) The set of theories is vast, and typically it is impossible to solve any of the interesting cases exactly. A variety of approximation methods must be employed. This is to give you a flavor as to why it's hard to write a concise description of QFT.